# in while the message pops up six times and was supposed to jump out 5 times

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

i have problem with my app. When i use while-loop, my ask pops up 6 times when it should shows 5 time.

```
x=0
letter=input('xxx ')

while x!=5:
    if letter in correct:
        print("yes")
        letter = input('xxx ')
    else:
        print("No")
        letter = input('xxx')
    x += 1
```

and my output look like that

```
xxx a
yes
xxx b 
no
xxx a
yes
xxx b 
no
xxx a
yes
xxx b
```

i want to my xxx pop up only 5 times no more. What i have to do with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `while` loop prompts 5 times, and the `input` before the `while` loop prompts 1 time. 5 + 1 = 6.

For a general case of repeating an action `n` times, use a `for` loop. Also, move the `input` to before you check if it's correct or not:

```
n = 5 # however many times you would like to prompt for input

for _ in range(n):
    letter = input('xxx ')
    if letter in correct:
        print("Yes")
    else:
        print("No")
```

Also, you can make it shorter, albeit sacrificing a bit of readability:

```
for _ in range(n):
    print("Yes" if input('xxx ') in correct else "No")
```

---

Output:

```
In [1]: n = 5
   ...: correct = 'a'
   ...:
   ...: for _ in range(n):
   ...:     print("Yes" if input('xxx ') in correct else "No")
   ...:
xxx a
Yes
xxx b
No
xxx a
Yes
xxx b
No
xxx c
No
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop asks for the input 5 times, but you also ask for input before the loop, thus making 6 times.

I would also suggest using a `for` loop to repeat actions:

```
for _ in range(5):
    if letter in correct:
        print("yes")
        letter = input('xxx ')
    else:
        print("No")
        letter = input('xxx')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop runs 5 times (for x values of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4), but there is also an input outside of the loop, hence it runs a total of 6 times.

Try the following:

```
for _ in range(5):
   letter = input('xxx ')
   if letter in correct:
       print("Yes")
   else:
       print("No")
```